# Xcode tries to update itself again and again

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I have a desktop Mac computer and I want to update my Xcode version:

[image]

So after click `update` button the system start to download the `update` (`6GB`) and when its finish i see the same window again instead of start the `upgrade`.
I try to restart the system, download the `update` again and this button is still show that i need to download the `update`.

Why my update did not start ?
Maybe the `update` file is still on my system and i can start the update manually ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Xcode 10.2. This happens because the update wasn't successfully downloaded and you still have Xcode traces on your disk. I solved this by removing these files:

1. /Applications/Xcode.app
2. ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
3. ~/Library/Developer
4. ~/Library/MobileDevice
5. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
6. /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
7. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.bom
8. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.plist
9. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.bom
10. /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.plist

If you can't update Xcode from the Appstore app, then you should consider downloading the latest Xcode xip file from [Apple's developer program site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)